# How to correlate Device\HarddiskVolume[n] with drive letter

Tags: powershell

here is my script code so far:

```
$DynAssembly = New-Object System.Reflection.AssemblyName('SysUtils')
$AssemblyBuilder = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly($DynAssembly, [Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess]::Run)
$ModuleBuilder = $AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule('SysUtils', $False)

$TypeBuilder = $ModuleBuilder.DefineType('Kernel32', 'Public, Class')
$PInvokeMethod = $TypeBuilder.DefinePInvokeMethod('QueryDosDevice', 'kernel32.dll', ([Reflection.MethodAttributes]::Public -bor [Reflection.MethodAttributes]::Static), [Reflection.CallingConventions]::Standard, [UInt32], [Type[]]@([String], [Text.StringBuilder], [UInt32]), [Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention]::Winapi, [Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet]::Auto)
$DllImportConstructor = [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetConstructor(@([String]))
$SetLastError = [Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute].GetField('SetLastError')
$SetLastErrorCustomAttribute = New-Object Reflection.Emit.CustomAttributeBuilder($DllImportConstructor, @('kernel32.dll'), [Reflection.FieldInfo[]]@($SetLastError), @($true))
$PInvokeMethod.SetCustomAttribute($SetLastErrorCustomAttribute)
$Kernel32 = $TypeBuilder.CreateType()

$Max = 65536
$StringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max)

Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume | ? { $_.DriveLetter } | Sort-Object DriveLetter | % {
$ReturnLength = $Kernel32::QueryDosDevice($_.DriveLetter, $StringBuilder, $Max)

   if ($ReturnLength)
    {
    $DriveMapping = @{
    DriveLetter = $_.DriveLetter
    VolumeName = $_.Label
    FileSystem = $_.FileSystem
    SerialNumber = $_.SerialNumber
    "Capacity (GB)" = $_.Capacity | Measure-Object -Sum | Foreach {"{0}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))}
    "FreeSpace (GB)" = $_.FreeSpace | Measure-Object -Sum | Foreach {"{0}" -f ([math]::round(($_.Sum / 1GB),2))}
    DevicePath = $StringBuilder.ToString()
    } 

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $DriveMapping | Select-Object DriveLetter, VolumeName, FileSystem, "Capacity (GB)", "FreeSpace (GB)", SerialNumber, DevicePath | Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
}
```

But I see multiple headers in my table output. It seems that the PSObjects must be merged.

Please assist. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `Format-Table -AutoSize` in your code while processing the `Foreach`. Apply it only on the output:

```
$output = 1..4 | %{

    $DriveMapping = @{
        DriveLetter = "DriveLetter$_"
        VolumeName = "Label$_"
        FileSystem = "FileSystem$_"
        SerialNumber = "SerialNumber$_"
        "Capacity (GB)" = "Capacity$_"
        "FreeSpace (GB)" = "FreeSpace$_"
        DevicePath = "StringBuilder$_"
    } 

    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $DriveMapping | Select-Object DriveLetter, VolumeName, FileSystem, "Capacity (GB)", "FreeSpace (GB)", SerialNumber, DevicePath #| Format-Table -AutoSize
}
$output | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: I'd also use [PSCustomObject] directly instead of the hashtable $DriveMapping, no need to use a Select-Object to keep the order of the properties then.